# SSH disconnects on changing expired password

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, password-management

I enabled password expiration on my Debian 8 server and today my password expired.
When I login through SSH, the server forces me to change my password now. I had to enter the old password, specify a new password and also confirm my new password.
After entering everything correctly, the SSH session is closed. (SSH Client disconnects) The password didn't change, it's the old expired password again. So I'm forced to change the password again, without success.
My issue is the same like [PuTTY Session Closed on Expired Password Over SSH Connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/50759/putty-session-closed-on-expired-password-over-ssh-connection) but I'm unable to administrate the server because there is no other account to login.

Comment: It is normal that the session closes after the change of password, but you should be able to login with a new password (unless it will expire immediately).

Comment: Check your system logs.

Comment: Yes, but the password didn't change at all. It's the old password again, not the new one. So, when logging in again, I'm forced to change the password again, it's an infinite loop and the password wont change.

@MichaelHampton How? - There is no other account to login, only this one with expired password.

Comment: Does this mean you're locked out of your server?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Sadly yes.

Comment: Login as root, or use the console, or a rescue system, or mount the hard drive to another computer, or something...

Comment: Root-Login is disabled, it's a remote server.
I'll try using a rescue system, but I wanted to keep the server running - Thanks anyway.

Comment: If there's a remote console, then maybe logging in "locally" through the console will allow the password reset to work.